# Regex redirect to include any sub-domain

Tags: regex, redirect

-We used to use sub-domains for our various office locations (eg. http://foo1.bar.com/ and http://foo2.bar.com) and each of these locations had a different email disclaimer that contained a URL to a privacy policy for their location (eg. http://foo1.bar.com/privacy).

We now use folders instead of subdomains for different locations (eg. http://bar.com/foo1 or http://bar.com/foo2), and a group-wide privacy policy (eg. http://bar.com/privacy).

In our website host's configuration (**WPengine with apache/nginx back-end**) we have 15 or so regex redirects for these old sub-domains that look like

```
Rule: 45
Domain: foo1.bar.com
Source: ^.*
Destination: https://bar.com/foo1/
Type: 301 Permanent
```

How would I write a single rule that allows for any sub-domain's privacy page URL to redirect to the group-wide privacy page (eg. *.bar.com/privacy > https://bar.com/privacy/) but still allow for the catchall redirect I have above?

Or do I have to create a privacy page specific redirect for each sub-domain and place them above the catchalls?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing

```
location *.bar.com/privacy{

proxy_pass http://bar.com/privacy;
....
}
```

Read this, it will be helpful

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms#matching-location-blocks